# Learning Objective-C: "Command /Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1" when compiling

Tags: objective-c, ios

There seems to be lots of posts regarding that error message but I couldn't find one that has something to do with actual code. I have an Xcode 4.0 project called `prog1`, and inside it is a single file `main.m`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Fraction : NSObject
    -(void) print;
    -(void) setNumerator: (int) n;
    -(void) setDenominator: (int) d;
@end

@implementation Fraction {
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
}

-(void) print {
    NSLog(@"The fraction is %i/%i.", numerator, denominator);
}

-(void) setNumerator: (int) n {
    numerator = n;
}

-(void) setDenominator: (int) d {
    denominator = d;
}
@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    Fraction *f = [[Fraction alloc] init];
    [f setNumerator:5];
    [f setDenominator:6];
    [f print];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

This is the complete error message:

```
ProcessPCH /Users/rh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/prog1-djucagjboveiuwcnycgafzuugucf/Build/PrecompiledHeaders/prog1-Prefix-ethcjsncaxczlsgsnayacjarhmne/prog1-Prefix.pch.pth prog1/prog1-Prefix.pch normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/rh/Desktop/prog1/prog1
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
/Developer/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-print-source-range-info -fdiagnostics-show-category=id -fdiagnostics-parseable-fixits -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DDEBUG -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -fasm-blocks -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -iquote /Users/rh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/prog1-djucagjboveiuwcnycgafzuugucf/Build/Intermediates/prog1.build/Debug/prog1.build/prog1-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/rh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/prog1-djucagjboveiuwcnycgafzuugucf/Build/Intermediates/prog1.build/Debug/prog1.build/prog1-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/rh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/prog1-djucagjboveiuwcnycgafzuugucf/Build/Intermediates/prog1.build/Debug/prog1.build/prog1-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/rh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/prog1-djucagjboveiuwcnycgafzuugucf/Build/Intermediates/prog1.build/Debug/prog1.build/prog1-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/rh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/prog1-djucagjboveiuwcnycgafzuugucf/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/Users/rh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/prog1-djucagjboveiuwcnycgafzuugucf/Build/Intermediates/prog1.build/Debug/prog1.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/rh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/prog1-djucagjboveiuwcnycgafzuugucf/Build/Intermediates/prog1.build/Debug/prog1.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/rh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/prog1-djucagjboveiuwcnycgafzuugucf/Build/Products/Debug -c /Users/rh/Desktop/prog1/prog1/prog1/prog1-Prefix.pch -o /Users/rh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/prog1-djucagjboveiuwcnycgafzuugucf/Build/PrecompiledHeaders/prog1-Prefix-ethcjsncaxczlsgsnayacjarhmne/prog1-Prefix.pch.pth

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/rh/Desktop/prog1/prog1/prog1/prog1-Prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I don't see anything wrong here, but then again I just started learning Objective-C. Help?

Comment: Look under the issues tab of Xcode and see if there isn't some more detail provided there. There should be. Then the problem may be easier to understand, or you will have some more information to post here.

Comment: @Monolo Just posted the complete error message. Also, I'm running on Mac OSX 10.6.7 if that's anything.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the error is saying that it couldn't find a certain file (as quoted in the complete message above). I actually don't have `/Users/rh/Desktop/prog1/prog1/prog1/prog1-Prefix.pch` when I look through my file system but why is that and how do I change it?

Comment: That file is called the precompiled header. You may fix the problem by deactivating the use of precompiled headers within Xcode's build-settings.

Comment: @Till, you wanna make that an answer instead of a comment so I can choose it? Maybe explain as well how to deactivate precompiled headers. Also, I ended up re-creating the entire project and suddenly it just works. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question, I will quote Till's comment which he's too lazy to write as an answer. :)

"That file is called the precompiled header. You may fix the problem by deactivating the use of precompiled headers within Xcode's build-settings."