# when i build my project in xcode i got an error like clang error:input files not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang

I am trying to develop an application in xcode using objective c.When i build my project got an error like

```
clang error:no input files found
command/users/chairman/Desktop/xcode.app/contents/Developer/ToolChains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchains/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code1
```

Can anyone please help me in solving this?

Comment: ...stupid question, but do you have any source files yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have not copied entire error messages.
Anyhow, you should see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619865/clang-error-no-such-file-or-directory-users-waterskiingmithrill-development) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517926/learning-objective-c-command-developer-usr-bin-clang-failed-with-exit-code-1).

Comment: 1. Navigate to the directory containing the generated code that was copied over from the Eclipse environment. 2. Run: >headerdoc2html –o GeneratedDocDir GeneratedCodeDir >gatherheaderdoc GeneratedDocDir
we are not able to navigate into the generated code file we gave path like /users/chairman/desktop/mac_ios/importing_libraries_code
where in this importing_libraries_code is having the generated code. but it is showing no such file or directory found in TERMINAL